# using functions with loop in bash

Tags: bash

Having this odd issue with a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function printLinesFromInput {
    COUNTER=1
    while read USER; do 
        echo "Hello $USER"; 
        echo
    done < $1
}

while read USER; do 
    echo "Hello $USER"; 
done < south-park.txt

echo
echo "In function:"
echo $(printLinesFromInput south-park.txt)
```

It prints:

```
$ ./readFile.sh
Hello Eric
Hello Kyle
Hello Stan
Hello Kenny

In function:
 Hello Kenny
```

The function is not echoing all four lines of the file.
I am wondering why is this the case.
The input file south-park.txt is:

```
Eric
Kyle
Stan
Kenny
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but was not able to reproduce your problem on Bash 4.4.12 in Cygwin; the "in function" output was `Hello Eric Hello Kyle Hello Stan Hello Kenny` as expected (on one line because of `$()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the input file `south-park.txt` may contain `CR LF` line breaks.
Try to say:

```
 ./readFile.sh | less
```

Then you'll see:

```
Hello Eric
Hello Kyle
Hello Stan
Hello Kenny

In function:
Hello Eric^M Hello Kyle^M Hello Stan^M Hello Kenny
```

To fix it, remove \r's in your input file or modify the function as:

```
function printLinesFromInput {
    COUNTER=1
    while read USER; do
        echo "Hello $USER" | tr -d '\r'
    done < $1
}
```

BTW if you want to insert line breaks between users, you'll need another trick :-).